# My collisions won't work

Tags: unity, c#

I have been banging my head against this one for a while. I am trying to implement a pickup mechanic, using OnTriggerEnter2D, however I cannot get it to work, my player just runs past the coin.

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class gemMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // variables
    private Vector2 startPosition;
    private Vector2 endPosition;
    private int speed = 4;
    private float maxDistance = 0.15f;
    private int count = 0;
    public TextMeshProUGUI countText;

    private void Start()
    {
        startPosition = transform.position;
        endPosition = transform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        endPosition.y = startPosition.y + (maxDistance * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed));
        transform.position = endPosition;
    }

    void SetCountText()
    {
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pickup"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Pickup");

            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count++;

            SetCountText();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Gem Component View]

[image: Player Component View]

A little bit of help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Post a screenshot of the inspector for the player as well.

Comment: I have just uploaded the Player component view.

Answer (score 2):

You said that you used `OnTriggerEnter2D()` in your description, but your code actually uses `OnTriggerEnter()`, which isn't compatible with 2D colliders.

Comment: Remember to change the function parameter from `Collider` to `Collider2D` as well. The entire function signature needs to exactly match what Unity looks for, or your code will not be invoked.

Comment: Hi guys, I have changed it to OnTriggerEnter2D and changed the Collider2D, I am still having the same results. I tried with OnCollisionEnter2D as well without a trigger, but no luck :(. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a rather easy fix. On your `gemMovement` you check if the other tag is `Pickup` but if a collision happens, this is going to be the player. So either the method should go as it is on the player or you need to check if the coin is colliding with the player.

You probably do not want to deactivate the player on collision as well.

Comment: Thank you, it worked :)!